# Not print out the wrong message if the date is wrong

Tags: java

I want to return the message "`Date is very wrong`" if the transaction date is greater than the computation date. Instead, it just prints "`-1 days`".

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Age {

    public static long computeAge(String transDate, String computeDate){
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        long lapseDays = 0;

        try {
            Date TDate = format.parse(transDate);
            Date CDate = format.parse(computeDate);

            long aging = CDate.getTime() - TDate.getTime();
            lapseDays = aging/(24*60*60*1000);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("Date is very wrong"); 
        }

        return lapseDays;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String transaction = "10/01/2014";
        String computation = "09/30/2014";
        System.out.println(computeAge(transaction, computation)+ " days");
    }
 }
```

Comment: you should uncode the intro.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you could call the method [`Date.after(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) and something like

```
Date TDate = format.parse(transDate);
Date CDate = format.parse(computeDate);
if (TDate.after(CDate)) {
  System.out.print("Date is very wrong");
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: @Butterflow Presumably from parsing.

Answer (score 1):

try this: change the return type to `String` of `computeAge()` method.

```
public class Test2 {

public static String computeAge(String transDate, String computeDate){
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    long lapseDays = 0;

    try {
        Date TDate = format.parse(transDate);
        Date CDate = format.parse(computeDate);

        long aging = CDate.getTime() - TDate.getTime();
        lapseDays = aging/(24*60*60*1000);
        if(lapseDays<0){
            return "Date is very wrong";
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print("Date is very wrong"); 
    }

   return lapseDays+" days";
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String transaction = "10/01/2014";
    String computation = "09/30/2014";
    System.out.println(computeAge(transaction, computation));
 }
 }
```

Comment: i don't think, that changing returning type is a good advice. Especially when changing numeric data to a string which cant be used to be parsed to numeric value again without some validation

Comment: as per their requirement they need `long` or `String` so better to make `String` that can handle both type.

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

Here is some easier code, using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library version 2.4. Joda-Time is far superior to the confusing and troublesome java.util.Date & .Calendar classes bundled with Java.

### `LocalDate`

In particular, Joda-Time offers a class to represent a date-only without time-of-day or time zone, [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html).

The java.time package built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time) also offers a LocalDate class.

### Test For All Outcomes

The question may be confusing three possible outcomes, and fails to test for the second:

- Either string input is invalid format, and cannot be parsed. (bad)
- The first date may occur after the second date, or is equal. (bad)
- The first date occurs before the second date. (good)

For more robust code, you should also do sanity-checks on the data, looking for dates that are too far in the past or in the future.

### Give Better Feedback

Note that I use different messages for each possible outcome. The code in the Question uses identical messages which leads to confusion.

### Example Code

Invalid string inputs are detected during parsing by throwing the Joda-Time exception, [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

```
String inputA = "10/01/2014";
String inputB = "09/30/2014";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy" );
try {
    LocalDate a = formatter.parseLocalDate( inputA );
    LocalDate b = formatter.parseLocalDate( inputB );
    int daysBetween = Days.daysBetween( a , b ).getDays();
    if ( a.isBefore( b ) ) {
        System.out.println( "First date is " + daysBetween + " days before second date." );
    } else {  // Else the same date or a is later than b.
        System.out.println( "Error: First date is same or later than second date." );
    }

} catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
    System.out.println( "Invalid date string." );
}
```